# Forward/Inverse Search Does Not work on certain tex files

Tags: viewers, forward-inverse-search, winedt

I have this weird issue with forward and inverse searches.
I am using WinEdt + Sumatra combination. The forward and inverse search works perfectly on certain some `.tex` files, but fails on some others.

Currently, I am working on a `.tex` file and the inverse search always points to the end of a section. Where ever I double click in a particular section of the pdf, the inverse search points to the end of that section in the `.tex` file.

Moreover, when I try to perform forward search (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>) from the `.tex` file, the section in the pdf file doesn't get highlighted.

There are other `.tex` files where both the searches work perfectly. What could be the issue with this `.tex` file?

Comment: Also are you using `\include`, `\import` etc. ?

Comment: percusse: I am not using \include or \import.

Kurt: The .tex file is a template that I have downloaded. So, I don't know which part might be causing the problem in order to build a MWE. If you do need to have a look at the template, it can be found here. http://www.pamitc.org/cvpr13/files/cvpr2013AuthorKit.zip

And yes, I am sure that I have configured WinEdt properly. I have been using this configuration to edit 3-4 other .tex files and none of them have given me any problems. I am using WinEdt  Build: 20120329  (v. 7.0).

Answer (score 3):

In TeXmaker `synctex` (*i.e.* `jump to pdf` or `jump to source`) fails if either the directory or the file name has a space. In TeXworks (and TeXnicCenter) `synctex` fails only if the *file name* contains a space. Maybe WinEdt behaves like TeXmaker.

Check if the offending file contains a space in its name, or if any of the directories used in the compilation process have a space in their names. Remember also to check if you have redirected the temporary or output files to separate directories.

Answer (score 2):

Although it appears to be somewhat inconsistent, forward and inverse search fails when searching a `.tex` file identified in the first include statement used in a root `.tex` file. The error reported is a file not found message.

To fix the problem, I just added one more include statement where the file name is excluded. For example, in my root `.tex` file I originally had

```
\include{Introduction}
\include{LinearSystemsODEs}
% etc.
```

and I changed it to

```
\include{}
\include{Introduction}
\include{LinearSystemsODEs}
% etc.
```

The same problem occurs when an \includeonly statement is used.

Answer (score 1):

You could have turned the "--src" option off. Click on it, to enable it.

Comment: This is what happened to me and it took me a while to figure out why the inverse search did not work. You can activate "--src" by clicking the box on the bottom status line to the right of TeX and UTF-8 box.