# How can I create the synctex file for the LaTeX source?

Tags: forward-inverse-search

I deleted the synctex file by mistake and I'd like to know if there's a way to recover it. I want to be able to Ctrl-click in the preview and jump to the corresponding place in the LaTeX source.

I'm using TeXworks. Recompiling the source won't work.

Comment: Is recompiling the source an option?

Comment: @giordano I tried doing that, but TeXworks doesn't generate the synctex file again.

Comment: Here: `pdflatex --synctex=1 source.tex`. Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Thank you! I erased the synctex file of another LaTeX source and when I recompile, the synctex file appears again and everything works fine. I don't know why this method doesn't work the file in question. Where should I enter your code?

Comment: I found the answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78899/forward-inverse-search-does-not-work-on-certain-tex-files)!

Comment: The name of the `tex` file had spaces. I replaced with spaces with _ and recompiled and now everything works fine.